# What's causing Intersection Observer API to respond differently when replacing synchronous logic with asynchronous logic?

Tags: javascript

## Context

I've used the "Intersection Observer API" to build an infinite scroll image gallery. Basically this API allows me to load more items when a certain dummy DOM element enters the viewport.

## Prototype

Currently the prototype is implemented for an “iPhone X” (375x812) mobile device only. See: http://urbexco-acceptance.droppages.com/min_rep_ex_working (use Chrome DevTools 'inspect' device toolbar to select the right resolution). The image gallery is generated based on 57 items in the "database". When scrolling down, first 15 elements are loaded, then 15 more elements are loaded, then another 15 elements are loaded into the DOM, then another 10 elements are loaded, and finally 2 elements are loaded. When there are still more than 15 items left to be loaded, they are added using the following logic:

```
function addItems(n){

    // Append new items to .items-wrapper
    var items = document.querySelector('.items-wrapper');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var url = 'https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/09742e38c25b3e1d9716e02f8e76e87d/89fc0bda6a2c446a8e9e0d8adbc9a4fe.jpg';

        width = 170.5;
        height = 246;

        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.classList.add('item');
        items.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=" + '"' + url + '"' + "width=" + '"' + width + '"' + "height=" + height + "/>";
    }

}
```

**Minimal Working Example (no mobile view possible)**

https://jsfiddle.net/9jqgzymo/

## Objective

Since image width and height are currently hardcoded, I am now trying to assign width and height dynamically based on the image url. I try to achieve this using the `getMeta()` function:

```
function addItems(n){

    // Append new items to .items-wrapper
    var items = document.querySelector('.items-wrapper');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var url = 'https://img01.ztat.net/article/spp-media-p1/09742e38c25b3e1d9716e02f8e76e87d/89fc0bda6a2c446a8e9e0d8adbc9a4fe.jpg';
        getMeta(url);           
    }

}

function getMeta(url){   
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        res = calculateAspectRatioFit(this.width, this.height, 170.5, 246)
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.classList.add('item');
        var items = document.querySelector('.items-wrapper');
        items.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=" + '"' + url + '"' + "width=" + '"' + res.width + '"' + "height=" + res.height + "/>";
    };
    img.src = url;
}

function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
    return { width: srcWidth*ratio, height: srcHeight*ratio };
}
```

## Challenge

When implementing it this way, I see that - on initiation - already 30 items from the "database" where added to the DOM. Sometimes even all of them? Currently the non-working prototype is implemented for an “iPhone X” (375x812) mobile device only. See: http://urbexco-acceptance.droppages.com/min_rep_ex_not_working (use Chrome DevTools 'inspect' device toolbar to select the right resolution). For a minimal working example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/k3p20qno/

## Key question

What is the reason that with my new implementation, on initiation, already 30 or more items are added to the DOM? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem lies in here :

```
function getMeta(url){   
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        res = calculateAspectRatioFit(this.width, this.height, 170.5, 246)
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.classList.add('item');
        var items = document.querySelector('.items-wrapper');
        items.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=" + '"' + url + '"' + "width=" + '"' + res.width + '"' + "height=" + res.height + "/>";
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Above code does an async operation with onload event. So it doesn't wait to image to be loaded.
If you turn this into a function that returns a promise you will get the result that you expect. And you should await where you call the function. That way when you add the intersection element it will add it as the last element of the items wrapper. If you don't await it will be added as the first element because the loading of the images will be async and will happen later.

```
  function getMeta(url){   
        var img = new Image();
      const p = new Promise(resolve =>{
       img.onload = function(){
            console.log( this.width+' '+ this.height );
            res = calculateAspectRatioFit(this.width, this.height, 170.5, 246)
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.classList.add('item');
            var items = document.querySelector('.items-wrapper');
            items.appendChild(newDiv);
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=" + '"' + url + '"' + "width=" + '"' + res.width + '"' + "height=" + res.height + "/>";
            resolve()
        }; 
      })
       
        img.src = url;
      return p;
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpvrLb5s/)

**Edit:** Put the `resolve()` in the right position which is inside the `load` function

Comment: Hi Eldar. Thanks for your insights on the matter. 

I was looking into await/async myself, but I didn't figure out the fact that I needed to work with a Promise around the onload, so thanks for pointing that out.

Unfortunately, from what I see, the behaviour remains the same? On initiation the code still loads all items into the DOM? The desired outcome is an initial load of 15 items (cfr. initial prototype) and additional loads of 15 items triggered by each downward scroll of the user that reaches the bottom of the page. Any more thoughts from your side?

Comment: @user1098973 it was a typo that i mistakenly placed the resolve callback outside of the onload function. See updated answer and fiddle